# Primefaces Date Value does not set correct value after ajax dateSelect event update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

In my code i have two date values stored in my bean, one (recallDate) is selected from calendar component by user. For the other one (recallFinishDate) i am trying to calculate the finish date which is two weeks after of the selected recallDate.

I want to show the updated finish date by rerendering it, when a user selects a recall date.

The problem is, when i select a value from calendar, i can see that my **calculateRecallFinish** method runs **correctly** and makes the correct calculation but after my method finishes, it keeps setting the todays date value on recallDate and recallFinishDate by default.

I want to see the selected and calculated recall dates on frontend.

I'm currently using primefaces version 6.0

Here is my code

```java
@Named("updatePlanning")
@ViewScoped
public class UpdatePlanningView extends BaseView implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7354105373870032645L;
   private Date recallDate = new Date();
   private Date recallFinishDate = new Date();

   /**
     Initialize methods and getter setters are here
   
   **/

   public void calculateRecallFinish(SelectEvent e) {
      recallDate = (Date) e.getObject();
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTime(recallDate);
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (14));
      recallFinishDate = calendar.getTime();
   }
}
```

And my frontend xhtml code is like this;

```html
<p:calendar id="recallDate" value="#{updatePlanning.recallDate}" showOn="button" navigator="true" styleClass="form-calendar">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
      listener="#{updatePlanning.calculateRecallFinish}" global=true update="@form"> </p:ajax>
</p:calendar>

<p:inputText disabled="true" id="recallFinishDate" value="#{updatePlanning.recallFinishDate}">
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. The problem was the ViewScoped import.

I've changed the import from javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped to javax.faces.view.ViewScoped and now it works